# Parsing command line arguments in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am currently working on a project that requires parsing command line arguments. So far I have been following [this tutorial](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tutorials/Programming_Haskell/Argument_handling), which has been incredibly helpful, but I can't figure out how to return a variable (--author=example) in the arguments. I also can't figure out why **`parse [] = getContents`** causes an error (I had to uncomment it).

Here is my code:

```
module Main where

import qualified System.Environment as SE
import qualified System.Exit as E
import qualified Lib as Lib

main = do
  args <- SE.getArgs
  rem <- parse args
  Lib.someFunc
  putStrLn rem
  putStrLn "Hello"

tac  = unlines . reverse . lines

parse ["--help"]    = usage   >> exit
parse ["--version"] = version >> exit
parse ["--author=xyz"] = return "xyz"
-- parse ["--author=?"] = ?
{-
this is the code I am trying to figure out... how do I get parse the passed in variable name?
-}

-- parse []            = getContents
{-
the above line generates this error when I run 'main' in GHCi:

  *Main> <stdin>: hIsEOF: illegal operation (handle is semi-closed)
  Process intero exited abnormally with code 1

-}
parse fs            = concat `fmap` mapM readFile fs

usage   = putStrLn "Usage: gc2"
version = putStrLn "gc2 -- git-cal in Haskell2010 - 0.1"
exit    = E.exitWith E.ExitSuccess
die     = E.exitWith (E.ExitFailure 1)
```

Comment: `getContents` fetches ALL the input, and requires that you don't read anything from input after that. Are you satisfying that contract? Check `Lib.someFunc`, for instance.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense (and it seems the error was because I was using System.Process in Lib.someFunc).

Comment: There are argument parsing libraries out there. Is there a reason not to use one of them?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: I am ignorant of those. Would you mind pointing me towards them?

Comment: [optparse-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.14.0.0/docs/Options-Applicative.html) is the powerful preferred parser by many developers.  However, for simple jobs I like the aptly named [simple-get-opt](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simple-get-opt).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: thank you!

Answer (score 7):

To follow up on @ThomasM.DuBuisson comment [optparse-applicative](https://www.stackage.org/package/optparse-applicative) is a great package for cli and arguments parsing. There is also another package [optparse-simple](https://www.stackage.org/package/optparse-simple) that is built on top of the previous one and has a few helpers that simplify things a bit.

Just so you can get started with `optparse-applicative` here is an implementation of your example:

```
data Options = Options
  { author :: String
  }

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let ver = "gc2 -- git-cal in Haskell2010 - 0.1"
  args <-
    execParser $
    info
      (Options <$>
       strOption (long "author" <>
                  short 'a' <>
                  help "Name of the author.") <*
       infoOption ver (long "version" <>
                       short 'v' <>
                       help "Display version and exit.") <*
       abortOption ShowHelpText (long "help" <>
                                 short 'h' <>
                                 help "Display this message."))
      (progDesc "Very powerful tool." <> fullDesc)
  putStrLn $ author args
```

And usage example from GHCi:

```
λ> :main
Missing: (-a|--author ARG)

Usage: <interactive> (-a|--author ARG) [-v|--version] [-h|--help]
  Very powerful tool.
*** Exception: ExitFailure 1
λ> :main --version
gc2 -- git-cal in Haskell2010 - 0.1
*** Exception: ExitSuccess
λ> :main --help
Usage: <interactive> (-a|--author ARG) [-v|--version] [-h|--help]
  Very powerful tool.

Available options:
  -a,--author ARG          Name of the author.
  -v,--version             Display version and exit.
  -h,--help                Display this message.
*** Exception: ExitSuccess
λ> :main --author Me
Me
```

Comment: What's the `ShowHelpText`?

Comment: @przemo_li It is a type constructor that will fail parsing the cli arguments and terminate the program while showing the help test, i.e. options, descriptions and such.
https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.5/optparse-applicative-0.14.2.0/Options-Applicative.html#t:ParseError